# I cannot insert to the mysql database with spring batch

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to insert the information from an excel file to mysql, I am using the extension of springbatch excel to read the file but when trying to insert the mysql it gives an error apparently it does not send the information i shared my `batch.config`

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Pagare pagare() {
        return new Pagare();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public ItemProcessor<Pagare, Pagare> itemProcessor() {
        return new PagareItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        // dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pagare");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql"));
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql"));
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Pagare> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper() {
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Pagare> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setPrototypeBeanName("pagare");
        return fieldSetMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    ItemReader<Pagare> pagareReader() {
        PoiItemReader<Pagare> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("pagares.xlsx"));
        reader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    private RowMapper<Pagare> excelRowMapper() {
        return new RowMapperImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Pagare> beanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider() {
        return new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Pagare> JdbcBatchItemWriter(DataSource dataSource,
                                                  BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Pagare> sqlParameterSourceProvider) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Pagare> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(sqlParameterSourceProvider);
        jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql("insert into pagare(operacion,id,contrato,tipo,analista,fechaCargaDocumento,estadoOperacion,fechaCambioEstado) values (:operacion, :id, :contrato, :tipo, :analista, :fechaCargaDocumento, :estadoOperacion, :fechaCambioEstado)");

        return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job jobCsvMysql(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step step) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobCsvMysql").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step).end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                      ItemReader<Pagare> pagareReader, ItemWriter<Pagare> writer, ItemProcessor<Pagare, Pagare> processor) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Pagare, Pagare>chunk(6)
                .reader(pagareReader).processor(processor).writer(writer).build();
    }

}
```

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into pagare(test1,id,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Column 'id' cannot be null; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Column 'test2' cannot be null

I tried changing the values ​​of my bd and my model and I have the same result, the reason why I use BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider is because my parameters of the insert are equal to those of my property of my model that I leave below

```
public class Pagare {
    private String operacion;
    private String rut;
    private String contrato;
    private String tipo;
    private String analista;
    private String fechaCargaDocumento;
    private String estadoOperacion;
    private String fechaCambioEstado;




    public String getOperacion() {
        return operacion;
    }

    public void setOperacion(String operacion) {
        this.operacion = operacion;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getAnalista() {
        return analista;
    }

    public void setAnalista(String analista) {
        this.analista = analista;
    }

    public String getFechaCargaDocumento() {
        return fechaCargaDocumento;
    }

    public void setFechaCargaDocumento(String fechaCargaDocumento) {
        this.fechaCargaDocumento = fechaCargaDocumento;
    }

    public String getEstadoOperacion() {
        return estadoOperacion;
    }

    public void setEstadoOperacion(String estadoOperacion) {
        this.estadoOperacion = estadoOperacion;
    }

    public String getFechaCambioEstado() {
        return fechaCambioEstado;
    }

    public void setFechaCambioEstado(String fechaCambioEstado) {
        this.fechaCambioEstado = fechaCambioEstado;
    }

    public String getRut() {
        return rut;
    }

    public void setRut(String rut) {
        this.rut = rut;
    }

    public String getContrato() {
        return contrato;
    }

    public void setContrato(String contrato) {
        this.contrato = contrato;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pagare [operacion=" + operacion + ", rut=" + rut + ", contrato=" + contrato + ",tipo=" + tipo + ",analista=" + analista + ",fechaCargaDocumento=" + fechaCargaDocumento + ",estadoOperacion=" + estadoOperacion + ",fechaCambioEstado=" + fechaCambioEstado + "]";
    }
```

my item processor is this

```
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PagareItemProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public Pagare process(Pagare pagare) throws Exception {

        LOG.info("Processing " + pagare);

        final String initCapAnalista = pagare.getAnalista().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + pagare.getAnalista().substring(1);
        final String initCapTipo = pagare.getTipo().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + pagare.getTipo().substring(1);
        Pagare transformedPagare = new Pagare();
        transformedPagare.setOperacion(pagare.getOperacion());
        transformedPagare.setAnalista(initCapAnalista);
        transformedPagare.setTipo(initCapTipo);
        return transformedPagare;


    }

    }
```

this picture of console when read the file and error
[image]

Comment: It looks like `test2` in your `Pagare` item is `null` and the corresponding column in your table is not nullable. So either change the column to be nullable or make sure to validate items before writing them (this can be done using a `BeanValidatingItemProcessor` for example, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#validatingInput)

Comment: If I can read the information in the excel file console, is it valid? I will edit the post I upload the capture

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using named parameters in your INSERT statement, you need to inject a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` into your writer. Also make sure that the parameter names match the property names of the `Pagare` type (which you did not share).

Comment: I don't work with the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate I still get the same error add my class model

Comment: The information you provided is inconsistent. In your code the INSERT statement reads `insert into pagare(operacion,id,contrato,tipo,analista,fechaCargaDocumento,estadoOperacion,fechaCambioEstado) values (...)`, but in the error message it reads `insert into pagare(test1,id,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,test8) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`. Can you please also share the CREATE TABLE statement from your `schema-mysql.sql`.
Another thing I noticed is that the INSERT statement is referring to a named query parameter `:id`, but `Pagare` has a field `rut` instead.